# Mobile version of wordpress site on subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

I have desktop version of Wordpress site and now need to make mobile friendly. Not exactly sure how to aproach it. In case of my site I would imagine having both versions on same url, without "`http://mobile.`" subdomain and attack everything with media queries if possible (or even without). If major changes are needed in layout for whatever reason then simply do check in php and echo different HTML to the browser.

It seems quite common that mobile versions of website are located on "mobile" or "m" subdomain. What is advantage of having this on subdomain? Additional redirect is necessary I believe and this is never a good thing. So why is this so common?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect is bad.

You can achieve your objective using any of the below methods:

1. To implement it on UI level (Client side), use `responsive design` with your theme.
2. To implement it on back-end (Server side), use `WP Mobile Detect` or check out the following link: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect#projects-that-are-using-the-class

Ae per the complexity of the porting process, you can decide to choose any of them.